# BeautfulSoup issues to login in to website with request session

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I using code below to make a login in a website en be able to **scrape** data from my own profile page.
However same after i make get from URL of profile the selector(soup) only returns data from login page.
I still dont be able to found a reason for that.

```
import requests
from requests import session
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


login_url='https://caicara.pizzanapoles.com.br/Account/Login'

url_perfil = 'https://caicara.pizzanapoles.com.br/AdminCliente'

payload = {
    'username' : 'MY_USERNAME',
    'password' : 'MY_PASSWORD'
}


with requests.session() as s:
    s.post(login_url, data = payload)
    r = requests.get(url_perfil)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    print(soup.title)
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you  need to use your session object `s` for all the requests.

```
r = requests.get(url_perfil)
```

changes to

```
r = s.get(url_perfil)
```

A `__RequestVerificationToken` is sent in the POST data when you try to login - you may need to send it too.

It is present inside the HTML of the `login_url`

```
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" value="..."
```

This means you `.get()` the login page - extract the token - then send your `.post()`

```
r = s.get(login_url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
token = soup.find('input', {'name': '__RequestVerificationToken'})['value']
payload['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token

r1 = s.post(login_url, data=payload)
r2 = s.get(url_perfil)
```

You may want to save each request into its own variable for further debugging.

Comment: Sure, it makes mor sense. However now it returns some error relates to arguments of find. ```
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-816cc40d71fd> in <module>
     13 
     14     soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
---> 15     token = soup.find('input', name='__RequestVerificationToken')['QHlUQaro9sNo4lefL59lQRtbuziHnHtolV7Xm_Et_3tvnZKZnS4gjBBJZakw7crW0dyXy_lok44RozrMAvWm61XXGla5tC3AuZlgXC4GukA1']
     16     payload['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token
     17 

TypeError: find() got multiple values for argument 'name'```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Karl for yout return,

But it dont worked fine.
U change my code using tips as you mentioned above.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

login_url = 'https://caicara.pizzanapoles.com.br/Account/Login'
url = 'https://caicara.pizzanapoles.com.br/AdminCliente'
data = {
    'username': 'myuser',
    'password': 'mypass',
}

with requests.session() as s:
    r = s.get(login_url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    token = soup.find('input', name='__RequestVerificationToken')['value_of
    _my_token']
    payload['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token

    r1 = s.post(login_url, data=payload)
    r2 = s.get(url_perfil)
```

However it returns a error below.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-140-760e35f7b327> in <module>
     13 
     14     soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
---> 15     token = soup.find('input', name='__RequestVerificationToken')['QHlUQaro9sNo4lefL59lQRtbuziHnHtolV7Xm_Et_3tvnZKZnS4gjBBJZakw7crW0dyXy_lok44RozrMAvWm61XXGla5tC3AuZlgXC4GukA1']
     16 
     17     payload['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token

TypeError: find() got multiple values for argument 'name'
```